# A version of Hurwitz's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

**Question**: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic function in $\mathbb{C}$ which converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ to a polynomial $p$ of degree $m$.  Prove that for $n$ big enough, $f_n$ has at least $m$ zeros (counting multiplicities).

**Attempt**:  I know this is a version of Hurwitz's theorem, but I don't want to just say "by Hurwitz".  If $f_n$ is identically $0$, then the problem is trivial, so let's assume this isn't the case.  For any point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, there is an $r>0$, such that $0<|z-z_0|\leq r$.  Let $|z-z_0|=r$ be the circle $C$.  Then, by uniform convergence on $C$ (since $C$ is compact as it is a circle) we have $\frac{1}{f_n(z)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{p(z)}$, and $\frac{1}{f'_n(z)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{p'(z)}$.  So, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f'_n(z)}{f_n(z)}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz.$$  Therefore, since the integral on the LHS gives the number of zeros of $f_n(z)=0$ inside $C$, we see that $f_n$ and $p$ have the same number of zeros inside $C$.  Letting $r\rightarrow\infty$ gives the result on $\mathbb{C}$.

Do you see anything wrong with the proof?  In particular, is there anything going on with the "for $n$ big enough" or "counting multiplicites" parts of the problem that I should be careful about?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your argument:

> For any point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, there is an $r>0$, such that $0<|z-z_0|\leq r$.

What is $z$ here?

> Then, by uniform convergence on $C$ (since $C$ is compact as it is a circle) we have $\frac{1}{f_n(z)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{p(z)}$, ...

You need that $p(z) \ne 0$ on $C$ for this conclusion.

> ... and $\frac{1}{f'_n(z)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{p'(z)}$.

That may be, but what you need is that $f_n'(z) \to p'(z)$ on $C$.

I would start as follows: First, we can assume that the degree $m$ of $p$ is at least one (otherwise there is nothing to show), so that $p$ is a non-constant polynomial. Then choose $r > 0$ so large that all roots of $p$ are inside $\{ |z| < r \}$. Now consider the circle $C$ centered at the origin with radius $r$. Note that $p$ is non-zero on $C$.

Finally show that $f_n'/f \to p'/p$ uniformly on $C$, and apply the argument principle.

Comment: This may be a silly question: since $f_n\rightarrow p$, then we get $\frac{1}{f_n}\rightarrow\frac{1}{p}$.  The same should hold for the derivatives of each then, right?  So, shouldn't $\frac{f'_n}{f_n}\rightarrow\frac{p'}{p}$, by just combining them?

Comment: @User7238: $f_n' \to p'$ is a basic property of sequences of holomorphic functions, it follows e.g. from the Cauchy integral theorem. Then $\frac{f'_n}{f_n}\to \frac{p'}{p}$ is an elementary calculation, that is true for any (not necessarily holomorphic) sequences of functions, if both numerator and denominator converge uniformly, and the limit of the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Than k you so much!